# How Will A Static HashCode Effect Performance (C#)

Tags: c#, android, iphone, xamarin.forms

Generally, I intend for every class I have created in my project to be optimized inside of any collection and useable with the IEqualityComparer and IEquatable interfaces.

How will ignoring the GetHashCode method by returning a static int (like 0) whenever a GetHashCode method is required affect memory allocation and performance? Are there any issues that can be cause by doing this? Will calculating a value be beneficial for optimization? And ultimately, is it worth my time to go back and properly calculate a HashCode for every class in my project?

Comment: Haven't u read the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-8.0#remarks) and the [notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-8.0#notes-to-inheritors) of the GetHashCode method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always return 0 in `GetHashCode()`, it will significantly slow down performance when those objects are used in a `HashSet`, or as keys in a `Dictionary`, or other data structures that rely on `GetHashCode()`. If you don't plan on using those objects in data structures, `GetHashCode()` can be ignored.

I suggest you look into how the `HashSet`, `Dictionary`/`Map`/`HashTable` data structures actually work. When you've figured that out use `System.Hashcode.Combine` as shown here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0070